# How to get groups that user belong to?

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api

Using Graph Service, I have tried to get list of groups that user belong to. Here is my sample code:

```
var userMemberOf = null;
var userMemberGroups = null;
const GraphService = require('graph-service');
const ClientCredentials = require('client-credentials');

const tenant = 'my-company.com';
const clientId = '0b13aa29-ca6b-42e8-a083-89e5bccdf141';
const clientSecret = 'lsl2isRe99Flsj32elwe89234ljhasd8239jsad2sl=';

const credentials = new ClientCredentials(tenant, clientId, clientSecret);

const service = new GraphService(credentials);

service.get('/users/tnguyen482@my-company.com/memberOf').then(response => {
    userMemberOf = response.data;
});

var settings = {
    "securityEnabledOnly": true
}
service.post('/users/tnguyen482@my-company.com/getMemberGroups', settings).then(response => {
    userMemberGroups = response.data;
});
```

The data return from both get & post method was an empty list. I have tried another user id but the result is the same. Am I correct when using method memberOf and getMemberGroups to get list of groups that user belong to? Does my sample code correct?

Comment: When the user is in no group graph will return an empty result.
Otherwise, when an error occured (e.g. insufficient rights or user not found) an corresponding status with an errormessage will be returned.
The operations you are using seem to be correct.
If you want to rule out that your code is incorrect, 
you should try executing the operations in the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).
Its a great tool for debugging and you can even login for access to your own data.

Comment: If you make your comment to be an answer, I would check it to be a correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user is in no group graph will return an empty result.
Otherwise, when an error occured (e.g. `accessDenied` or `user not found`) an corresponding http-status with an errormessage will be returned (more information in the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/errors)).

The operations you are using seem to be correct.

If you want to rule out that your operations/code is incorrect, you should try executing the operations in the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). 
Its a great tool for debugging and you can even login for access to your own data.